libc Fatal signal 11 in Android BabylonJS React Native
I'm getting this error below when running on emulator:

libc Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr
0x7b03a8c6f4 in tid 10945 (mqt_js), pid 10810

If I run on a device I get

Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 0x76cfdba6f4
in tid 597 (mqt_js), pid 428

I'm using BabylonJS in my react native app. Below is my code:
import { useEngine, EngineView } from '@babylonjs/react-native';
import { ArcRotateCamera, Camera, Scene, SceneLoader } from "@babylonjs/core";
import '@babylonjs/loaders/glTF';

// Home () => {...
const engine = useEngine();
const [scene, setScene] = useState<Scene>();
const [camera, setCamera] = useState<Camera>();

    useEffect(() => {

        if (engine) {

           const gltfURL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/BoxAnimated/glTF/BoxAnimated.gltf';

           SceneLoader.LoadAsync(gltfURL, undefined, engine).then((loadScene) => {
                setScene(loadScene);
                loadScene.createDefaultCameraOrLight(true, undefined, true);
                (loadScene.activeCamera as ArcRotateCamera).alpha += Math.PI;
                (loadScene.activeCamera as ArcRotateCamera).radius = 10;
                setCamera(loadScene.activeCamera!);

            });
        }
    }, [engine]);

  return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <EngineView camera={camera} displayFrameRate={true} />
        </View>
    );
//... remaining code

I've ensure that my android emulator with https://github.com/BabylonJS/BabylonNative/blob/master/Documentation/AndroidEmulator.md but it even crashes on device too.

The fault address can be a clue. Use a debugger or a tool like gdb to analyze the memory at that address and understand what code might be trying to access it incorrectly

Signal 11 (SIGSEGV): Segmentation fault, indicating an attempt to access an invalid memory address.
Signal 7 (SIGBUS): Bus error, usually caused by accessing memory that doesn't exist or is not mapped.
